# Drupal webform registration processing payment via Stripe but user/contact is not completing registration

Tags: civievent, registration, stripe

Drupal webform for event registrations using Stripe as payment processor is receiving payments but not completing the event registration

Using Drupal 9, Civi 5.64.2, Stripe 6.9

Error in Civi Config and Log is:
Aug 28 11:10:20  [debug] Pay by Credit Card No matching contributions for event evt_3Nk750LNY7Ta5lgY1t1RmdEr

Aug 28 11:10:20  [info] Contribution 1912 updated successfully

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a complete fix or not but found that Civi configuration included an option for pay later which was not used in Drupal because we have had other issues trying that in the past.

By removing the "unused" pay later option we were successfully able to complete a payment with the requisite registration.

A caveat is that the application had already collect payments and completed registrations for 75 registrants before this issue popped up. Strange that it worked and then stopped as nothing was modified at that point or at all after registration started.  Putting it down as spooky actions at a distance!